# Why does $('#id') return true if id doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always wondered why jQuery returns true if I'm trying to find elements by id selector that doesnt exist in the DOM structure.

Like this:

```
<div id="one">one</div>

<script>
    console.log( !!$('#one') ) // prints true
    console.log( !!$('#two') ) // is also true! (empty jQuery object)
    console.log( !!document.getElementById('two') ) // prints false
</script>
```

I know I can use `!!$('#two').length` since length === 0 if the object is empty, but it seems logical to me that a selector would return the element if found, otherwise `null` (like the native `document.getElementById` does).

F.ex, this logic can't be done in jQuery:

```
var div = $('#two') || $('<div id="two"></div>');
```

Wouldnt it be more logical if the ID selector returned null if not found?

anyone?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**This behaviour was chosen because otherwise jQuery would regularly throw NullReference Exceptions**

Almost all jQuery functions return a jQuery object as a wrapper around the Dom elements in question, so you can use dot notation.

```
$("#balloon").css({"color":"red"});
```

Now imagine `$("#balloon")` returned *null*. That means that `$("#balloon").css({"color":"red"});`
would throw an error, rather than silently doing nothing as you would expect.

Hence, you just gotta use `.length` or `.size()`.

Comment: I was also thinking this was one of the reasons. But is it really a good idea to suppress errors this way? If the id is not found, I'd sure like to know where the error is thrown instead of debugging each chain.

Comment: This might be the behaviour you'd want if you are using the id selector, as ids are (normally) unique. But what if you were using a class selector, to close all dialogs/popups on a page. You wouldn't want the function to throw an error just because the user didn't happen to have any dialogs currently open. You'd want it to silently do nothing.

Comment: JavaScript does not have anything called NullReference Exceptions. Perhaps you mean `ReferenceError`?

Comment: I agree with throwing an error if certain element doesn't exist. Solid code throws exceptions and exceptions happen. :)
Unfortunately, jQuery isn't our best friend on that.

Answer (score 8):

**This is just how jQuery works.**

`$("#something")`

Object 0=div#something length=1 jquery=1.2.6

`$("#nothing")`

Object length=0 jquery=1.2.6

Answer (score 5):

You can come close to doing what you want by accessing the length the element, and combine with the ternary operator:

```
console.log(!!$('#notfound').length);  // false
console.log(!!$('#exists').length);    // true
var element= $('#notfound').length ? $('#notfound') : $('#exists');
console.log(element.attr('id'));  // outputs 'exists'
```

**As to the heart of the question:**

> Wouldnt it be more logical if the ID
>   selector returned null if not found?

No, not for the JQuery way of doing things - namely, to support chaining of JQuery statements:

```
    $('#notfound').hide("slow", function(){
      jQuery(this)
        .addClass("done")
        .find("span")
          .addClass("done")
        .end()
        .show("slow", function(){
          jQuery(this).removeClass("done");
        });
    });
```

Even though `notfound` doesn't exist this code will run without stopping script execution. If the initial selector returns null, you'll have to add in an if/then block to check for the null. If the addClass, find, end and show methods return null, you'll have to add an if/then block to check the return status of each. Chaining is an excellent way to handle program flow in a dynamically typed language like Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

It returns true because to Javascript it is a defined object therefore not false, and jQuery will always give you a new object regardless of whether the element is found or not - however the array length will be zero, e.g.

`$("span").length`

If you have no `<span>`, this will be zero, but it could be 1 or more.

You can write your own plugin to avoid repeated if statements as a Jquery plugin, like I did for [this one](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-extensions). It's fairly easy to do:

```
(function($)
{
        /* Checks if a jQuery object exists in the DOM, by checking the length of its child elements. */
        $.fn.elementExists = function()
        {
                ///     <summary>
                ///     Checks if a jQuery object exists in the DOM, by checking the length of its child elements.
                ///     </summary>
                ///     <returns type="Boolean" />
                return jQuery(this).length > 0;
        };
})(jQuery);
```

**Usage:**

```
if ($("#someid").elementExists())
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check the `.length` property of the jQuery object. Like this:

```
if($("#two").length > 0) { // exists...

} else { // doesn't exist

}
```

Comment: That's a nice one. It can actually yet be shortened: `if ($("#two").length)` should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you could think of the jQuery selector return value as a group containing 0..n elements, but never being null.

What you're probably really interested in is `$("#two")[0]`, which will give you the first actual element returned by the selector.

Comment: `$("#two:first")` will still return a jQuery object.