# Why my 'else' do not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does $(‘#id’) return true if id doesn’t exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076988/why-does-id-return-true-if-id-doesnt-exist)

I have a very simple js function:

```
function refresh(ltr) {
    if (board.find('p:contains("' + ltr + '")')) {
        board.find('p:contains("' + ltr + '")').show();
    } else {
        alert('Hello.');  
    }
}
```

Obviously I pass a string to ltr, it works fine if it contains the string but if not it do not fire the alert...

Do you know why?

Comment: I'd consider building your selector before the conditional to make it read easier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because `.find` returns a jQuery object which always evaluates to `true`

Try a boolean expression:

```
if( board.find('p:contains("' + ltr + '")').length > 0 )
```

Comment: @user1645985 What makes you think it was a "noob guy" that downvoted your question? While I didn't downvote, I'm sympathetic--simply logging the result of the selector or trying it in the JavaScript console would have shown why the conditional failed to do as you expected.

Answer (score 5):

`board.find()` will always return a jQuery collection, which will evaluate as truthy. You need:

```
board.find(...).length
```