# Why jQuery not throwing any error when object not found

Tags: jquery

I want to know, Is there any specific reason, why jQuery not throwing any error when object not found for the given selector.

For Example:

```
$("#content").css("color","red");
```

Here, there is no element with id "content",but it's not doing anything even error.

Comment: yes i know they're awesome :)

Comment: there isn't an error, because there are no results.

Comment: not having a element matching a selector is not an error

Comment: Hello, setting up your markup in a minimal way in a fiddle in order to re-create the error would help us help you.

Comment: Check Console to find out the `Javascript/Jquery` error

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem. You can just check if the selector gives a result. If so execute some code. If not, depening on your code, do nothing or do something else :)

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076988/why-does-id-return-true-if-id-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 6):

jQuery selector for return element collection having *zero* element when no match is found that is how it is designed. You can use `length` property to check if you got elements

```
if($('yourselector').length)
{
    //You got one or more elements
}
else
{
   //You haven't got any element.
}
```

Comment: indeed, this is what I mean!

Comment: Just to add, any selector will always return a jQuery object, therefore it is not null/undefined/empty, even if there are no matching elements. Using @Adil's method is the only way to determine if elements were found.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not the only way but the best for sure

Comment: True. Perhaps I should have said 'best practice is to...'

Answer (score 2):

*Define*

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
      notEmpty: function (atLeast) {
          const len = atLeast || 1;
          if (this.length < len)
              throw `unable to find ${len} element with selector : 
              '${this.selector}'. ${this.length} element is found.`;
          return this;
      }
  });
```

*Use*

```
let el = $(".at_least_one_element_selector").notEmpty();       
let el = $(".at_least_5_element_selector").notEmpty(5);
```